# pytest: How to get a list of all failed tests at the end of the session? (and while using xdist)

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, xdist

I would like to have a **list of all the tests that have failed** to be used **at the end of session**.

Pytest lets you define a hook `pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus)`, that is called at the end of the session, where I wish to have that list.

`session` is a `_pytest.main.Session` instance that has the attribute `items` (type `list`), but I couldn't find whether the each `item` in that list passed of failed.

1. How can a list of all failed tests could be retrieved at the end of the session?
2. How can it be done while using `pytest-xdist` plugin, where I would like to get that list in the master process. Using this plugin, `session` does not even have `items` attribute in the master:

   ```py
   def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
       if os.environ.get("PYTEST_XDIST_WORKER", "master") == "master":
            print(hasattr(session, "items"))  # False
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want results of the tests you can use hook `runtest_makereport`:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    if rep.when == 'call' and rep.failed:
        mode = 'a' if os.path.exists('failures') else 'w'
        try:  # Just to not crash py.test reporting
          pass  # the test 'item' failed
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work well when xdist is not in use, and I can save the failed tests to a global variable to be used by `pytest_sessionfinish` at the end. 
**When using xdist**, `pytest_runtest_makereport` is called only for the workers and not for master, so they can communicate through file, but a better solution is using `pytest_report_teststatus` and `pytest_runtest_logreport` that **are called in the master** and can be used to collect failed test.

Answer (score 40):

Run pytest with `-rf` to get it to print a list of failed tests at the end.

From `py.test --help`:

```
  -r chars              show extra test summary info as specified by chars
                        (f)ailed, (E)error, (s)skipped, (x)failed, (X)passed,
                        (p)passed, (P)passed with output, (a)all except pP.
                        Warnings are displayed at all times except when
                        --disable-warnings is set
```

Here's what you get:

```
$ py.test -rf
================= test session starts =================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.2, pytest-4.3.1, py-1.6.0, pluggy-0.7.1
[...]
=============== short test summary info ===============
FAILED test_foo.py::test_foo_is_flar
FAILED test_spam.py::test_spam_is_mostly_pork
FAILED test_eggs.py::test_eggs_are_also_spam
=== 3 failed, 222 passed, 8 warnings in 12.52 seconds ==
```

Comment: I use `pytest ... -rA` and it gives failures output before passed output, is there a way to make it give failures output at the end? So less scrolling up

Answer (score 5):

`--result-log` is deprecated. You can instead use `-v` to output the test case names as they run. If you pipe that into a file, you can query it. So if you're running your tests from a script you can do something like:

```
pytest -v | tee log.txt
grep -E '::.*(FAILURE|ERROR)' log.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use command line option `--result-log`:

test_dummy.py:

```
def test_dummy_success():
    return


def test_dummy_fail():
    raise Exception('Dummy fail')
```

Command line:

```
$ py.test --result-log=test_result.txt
```

Content of the test_result.txt

```
. test_dummy.py::test_dummy_success
F test_dummy.py::test_dummy_fail
 def test_dummy_fail():
 >       raise Exception('Dummy fail')
 E       Exception: Dummy fail

 test_dummy.py:6: Exception
```

Just search 'F' in first column and after that would be [file]::[test]

Comment: I would like to use this information in `pytest_sessionfinish` and this method means failed tests list is available only after the pytest process has exited.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted a concise report of failed tests and parametrized variations so went with `pytest_terminal_summary` in `conftest.py`:

```
def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config):
    terminalreporter.section('Failed tests')
    failures = [report.nodeid.split('::')[-1]
                for report in terminalreporter.stats.get('failed', [])]
    terminalreporter.write('\n'.join(failures) + '\n')
```

If you inspect `terminalreporter._session.items`, there's more information you can add to the report, this is just what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the details of only failing tests and save the logs into a file with command below. Logs also contain the trace of each test.

```
py.test -rf tests/ | tee logs.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I came access this question, trying to figure out internal data structure for the `session` instance.

Iterating over `session.items` you can check `rep_call.outcome` for string representation of the test result.

```
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    for item in session.items:
        print('{} {}'.format(item.name, item.rep_call.outcome))
```

With trivial test cases you get this

```
test_positive passed
test_negative failed
```

Comment: Could have given the whole function...I tried your solution..did not work for me.....
perhaps mention the pytest version you have used....and also a print of the result....and the test case that was run......

Comment: What exactly does not work?
Do you have skipped tests in your setup?

Comment: Says...item does not have rep_call

Comment: I guess it means that the failing test was not started.

What if you replace `item.rep_call.outcome` with `item.rep_call.outcome if hasattr(session_item, 'rep_call') else item.rep_setup.outcome`